# What is Surya Kriya? What is its significance? How it is different from other related practices?

Tags: practice, surya

What is Surya Kriya? What is its significance? How it is different from other related practices?
Is it part of Patanjali Sutras? I have not come across too many texts or videos explaining the same.

Comment: it seems yaggi vasudevji's contribution

Comment: New thing invented by him.. A modified version of surya namaskara

Comment: It's not Sadguru. That's sure. As he mostly conducts Kriya Yoga.